# MacBook Pro 15" Early 2011, top right corner of the screen getting too hot

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, screen

Since 10.9.3 update, I'm noticing a problem
first, as I mentioned, right side of the screen getting quite warm, as warm as base, where CPU and GPU fans resides.

second, even it's in sleep mode (blinking led) whole laptop is getting quite warm again, and draining battery like in normal operation (fans are not spinning).

I can not pinpoint the problem, no clues on net, I'm wondering if anyone else having these problems.

Comment: Okay, here's some development, when I was upgrading HDD and ram upgrades, I saw cables going over and near DVD burner.
Those are about camera, light sensor, bluetooth and wireless. I pulled out those cables and booted, no heating on the lid at all. I'm suspecting 10.9.3 update has something to do with wireless and bluetooth, causing overheat on the lid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple tries, I found out that camera cable causing the problem, I think it's there's a shortcut behind screen, camera cable is messed up. took apart the connection and 
battery draining issue resolved. there wasn't a sleeping problem actually, it was the shortcut all along,, nothing to do with update, it was sheer coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

- First the Sleep

use `Pmset -g` in Terminal to find out what is keeping it awake (publish here)

- second the HOT ! as rule of thumb anything above 50 Dgr Celsius would be hot for us, anything above 60 Dgr Celsius we almost can not touch.

However, your computer can handle that with no problem.

If you want to do more try running the Apple Hardware test to see if it comes with anything.

Press D during startup  Start up in Apple Hardware Test (AHT).

Comment: sleep settings are normal, nothing's keeping machine awake, led blinks, fans off.

the "hot" issue is not about the CPU or GPU, the screen lid is hot, only right side, especially right top corner of the screen. that's utterly weird.

Comment: While I trust your findings for the sleep mode, how come it is draining battery like in the normal mode?

Comment: That's is the money question, and what baffles me is, how the hell screen lid getting hot? (no, not in clamshell mode, and sleeping again)

Comment: well your screen does not supposed to be hot at all, so without spoiling your day, it might be it is dying a slow terrible death.

Answer (score 0):

Early 2011 13 inch MBP

eringen, thanks for your work in diagnosing the problem.

Had the same problem started two days ago where the right side of the screen gets really hot along with the top of the keyboard.  Gets hot even after closing the cover to sleep.

Launched photo booth which told me the camera is not connected.  Went in, disconnected the camera cable, and taped it up so it doesn't rattle or touch anything else.  It is now back to its old cool self and no chance anyone can hack in and use the camera.

Not much of a chance to replace it since it requires disassembling the screen.